# Is the author's comment true? (Ahlfors)

Tags: complex-analysis

In Ahlfors' complex analysis text, page 276 he writes

> The Weierstrass functions satisfy numerous identities which are best dealt with in an exercise section. They can be proved either by comparing two elliptic functions with the same zeros and poles (when $\sigma$-functions are involved), or by comparing elliptic functions with the same singular parts (when only $\wp$- and $\zeta$-functions are involved). *The following sequence of formulas is so arranged that we need to resort to this method only once*.

Now, problems 1 and 6 incorporate the $\sigma$ function, while problem 2-5 and 7 involve the $\wp$ and $\zeta$ functions only.

Does it mean that the last sentence of the author is false? After all both methods appear in two problems at least.

Thanks!